# Labels "Leak", "Rumour", "Confirmed" before Wordpress post title

Tags: wordpress, label

We are News site and want use something like this. Some people just can't understand the word written in the text that it's a **leak** or **confirmed** information. We also want to prevent this in this way. Is it possible to do / create it in any way? I was looking for plugins, some piece of code, but I didn't find anything. Is it possible?

Alternatively, we thought we would create categories and display them before the title of the article (just one word, **leak**, **confirmed**, etc.), but site works with multi-categories.

If anyone can advise, I'll be happy.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Even though your question is somewhat unclear, what I've understood is your are trying to sort your posts based on their "tags". For example you can "tag" a post as Leak and can display that tag on top of its featured image, possibly with the help of a plugin or if you theme supports it. You can also list posts under a certain tag. You can keep the default wordpress categories for your actual news categories such as Politics, Health, etc.

Comment: Hello ozgur, I want to make something like this https://ibb.co/ngQnxSd not just category. Just like on image. Word before post title to inform readers that news was not confirmed yet.

Comment: I think it is best to tag the post with the word you want to add, and then add that tag in front of the post. I'm will try to a code as an answer shortly. You can use it as a starting point and improve it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be using `jQuery`. I prefer using **[Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/)** plugin to add custom `php functions` or `javascript` to any wordpress theme.

After installing and activating Code Snippets, click **Add New** and paste the code below. I hardcoded each tag into the code buy it can be improved with a dynamic solution. As I don't see your html output I just wrote an approximate solution.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () { ?>
<script>
(function( $ ) {
  $(document).ready(
      function(){
        $(".tag-rumor .title").prepend ('<span class="customtag">Rumor</span>');
        $(".tag-leak .title").prepend ('<span class="customtag">Lean</span>');
        $(".tag-confirmed .title").prepend ('<span class="customtag">Confirmed</span>');
      }); 
})(jQuery);
</script>
<?php } );
```

CSS code for `customtag` class

```
.customtag {
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

I tested this here and it works: https://codepen.io/ozgursar/pen/KKMEENj

Comment: Hi @beatsk can you provide the link for your page where my code is running (if it can be shared publicly)

Comment: Hello, sure.. URL is www.spawn.sk . :)

Comment: Can you add rumor tag to this post please (for test purpose only) https://spawn.vosveteit.sk/cloud9-vyhodil-styroch-clenov-csgo-timu/

Comment: @beatsk I edited my code and tested in codepen (see the edited answer) and it works

Comment: you are perfect! :) In posts it is working perfect. :) I have a question anyway. How can I use it in block? something like on homepage where is news or custom taxonomies where are blocks, too? :) custom taxonomy i mean something like https://spawn.vosveteit.sk/?s=cloud+9 . Again, thank you so much.

Comment: @beatsk I'm happy to help :) I edited my code now in the answer. It should work on the example link you have given in your last comment.

Comment: Now its appeared in blocks, too. :) In that block it is not "inline" with title, but in posts still working perfectly.

Comment: It's because of your theme's css. This styling must be 
`.block .title a {display: inline;}` But you have `display: -webkit-box;`

Comment: Ah, oh.    .block .title a display: -webkit-box was my css edit. Now it is -webkit-inline-box and all working perfectly. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: @beatsk, if this or any other answer worked for you, please consider accepting the answer